# JAVA SQL Batch updates best way

Tags: java, sql, oracle, multithreading, batch-updates

I have a service that updates multiple tables through multiple services with in a transaction boundary, if one of them fails everything need to be rolled back. One of these SQL update has around 2k+ records to update and its done in two batches 1000 records at a time. Problem is this update is taking too long around 2mins sometimes and transaction timing out. Is there a way in this sql can be performed spanning multiple threads each thread updating 100 records. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database? Is this with jdbc?

Comment: DB is Oracle, yes jdbc

Comment: Jdbc is horribly slow. SQL*Loader will load a couple thousand rows  in a few seconds.

Comment: @NathanHughes the question was around updates, not inserts; so SQL Loader is not appropriate

Comment: That’s true. Though you could insert into a work table and execute a merge from there to the table to update ?

Comment: Whatever the method, the goal should be to execute a _single_ SQL update command, if possible, rather than iterate through a loop. Executing iterative SQL statements in for-next loops will _always_ be slow and generally make a rollback impossible if executed across multiple threads. If necessary, build a PL/SQL API procedure to handle multiple SQL commands (still try to avoid loops) and make a single call from the app to the procedure; this will allow you to better manage parallelization, transactions/rollbacks, and error handling in general over trying to do everything in Java.

Comment: Its all legacy code, for now we have managed it with running independent updates in separate threads. It improved the performance somewhat, at least not timing out.  Thanks all